# SQL query to increment row value based on timestamp

Tags: sql, getdate

I have a below SQL table which saves file coming from ERP. At times the file gets stuck and remains in the table. In order to avoid this I need to increment value in the "SequenceNumber" column by 1, so the next file gets processed.

In the below SQL table , if for the method pricebook- the file pricebook_1.xml is present for more than 5min than the current system timestamp, then "seq num" value should increment from 1190 to 1191.
How can I achieve this by using GETDATE() function

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

First thought is that you need to fix the process that's getting stuck.  However that might be outside of your control.

So, assuming that you're incrementing the `Seq Num` on the existing record rather than inserting a new record to the table, you could just run it as an `UPDATE` statement like this.  However if you only increment `Seq Num`, this update would just continue to run over and over since the date wouldn't change.  So I assume that you'd want to update the `Last Date Changed` column as well.

I'd strongly recommend that you add an additional flag column to this control table too, so that you can mark which records are complete/stuck/whatever, so that any process you have running against this table will be able to better know what subset of data it needs to be looking at.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET seq_num = seq_num + 1,
last_date_changed = GETDATE()
WHERE DATEDIFF(MI,last_date_changed,GETDATE())>5
AND method='pricebook'
```

Comment: That works great. Do I have to use a CASE statement if the same logic needs to be applied for the "method" billbook as well?

Comment: It all depends on how you want your updates to execute.  I'm not really clear on how you're managing this, so you might just have to play around with this.